# JS Calculating different than Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, formula, calc

Does JS have a different Syntax in calculating Math?

Excel: `1000 * (12 + 6.5 * 0.025) * ((1 + 0.025) ^ 40 - 1) / 0.025 = 819.784`

I copied this formula into my `script.js` and the result is quite different:

JS: `1000 * (12 + 6.5 * 0.025) * ((1 + 0.025) ^ 40 - 1) / 0.025 = 18.487.000`

I need the result of the excel-formula in my JS. Are some brackets in JS missing or something different?

Comment: Use `Math.pow((1 + 0.025), 40)` instead of `^`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do exponential math in JavaScript, use `Math.pow()` rather than `^`. So your equation in JavaScript should look like this:

```
1000 * (12 + 6.5 * 0.025) * (Math.pow((1 + 0.025), 40) - 1) / 0.025
```